# iOS how to ignore parent view receive touch event after child view handle it

Tags: ios, swift

Please take a look at the picture below:

[image]

I have a custom `UIControl` as `RangeSlider` which I implemented by follow [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/76433/how-to-make-a-custom-control-swift) tutorial. I place the `RangeSlider` inside a `FilterViewController` which can slide in or out.

On class `RangeSlider` I used 3 methods of `UIControl`: `beginTracking, continueTracking, endTracking` to handle touch event when user move the indicator of slider.

On class `FilterViewController` I used `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to handle touch event when user slide in or out.

**Problem**

When I try to move the indicator of slider, the `ViewController` also move. And the indicator is just move a bit. It seem to be the both of child view  and parent view received touch event.

**Question**

How can I ignore the parent view(`ViewController`) receive touch event?

Answer (score 0):

You should implement method of your PanGestureRecognizer delegate

> gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_:)

edit: please try

```
override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    guard let view = gestureRecognizer.view, view.isKind(of: UIControl.self) else {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have to observe every controls and check if whenever touch event happen with my controls. Is there any way easier or less complicated to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can write this in viewDidLoad().

```
self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: What is use of it?

Comment: Your parent controller view will not receive any touch events.

Answer (score -1):

This should help within FilterViewController (assuming it is touch delegate)

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if ([touch.view isDescendantOfView:self.tableView]) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Sorry for example in objective-c, you can easily convert it into swift. It means that the table or scrollview you use won't react on touches of its subviews (assuming RangeSlider is descendant subview of table view cell). Let me know if that doesn't help, I forced these issues in past by several different ways!

Comment: I tried to use that way but it is not work. The problem is: I only want my ViewController's View ignore touch event when it occurs on my `RangeSlider` but not the other subviews of ViewController's View.

Comment: got you! if ([touch.view isDescendantOfView:self.slider]) { doesn't work as well? Sorry, can't help in greater details without code, maybe you can share some little test project?